# Excel foreach over multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm a complete noob to excel and looking to do something like this:

```
For each item in column A
Get its corresponding value in column B and populate in column D
get its corresponding value in column C and populate in column E
```

the main problem I'm having is the number of rows in each column may differ. 
I think I would need a macro to do this.

How could I do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resort to a macro and the presence of something in column A dictates when you want to see something in column D & E, then consider the following functions:

IsBlank( A1) returns true if A1 is empty else false.

If( condition, trueResult, falseResult) returns the corresponding result based on the condition.

So for example, you could write the formula for D1 to be:

=If( IsBlank(A1), "", B1 * 2)

would set D1 to be twice that of B1. You can now copy and paste that formula down the D column to as far as you need and because the formula uses relative addressing (B1 instead of $B$1) the formula is updated for each cell to work on the corresponding row.

If this doesn't solve your issue then more detail on your problem would be useful.